# Why does adding an empty center() method crash the device, but not on simulator?

Tags: ios, swift

The following code crashes on initialization of `myView` when run on a device (5s, 8.2), but runs fine on the simulator (5s).  If I comment out the `center()` method of `TestView`, it runs on both the simulator and the device.

```
import UIKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    var myView = TestView(frame: CGRectZero)
}

class TestView: UIView {
    func center() {} // Works on simulator, fails on device
    func myCenter() {} // Works on both device and simulator
}
```

Some related questions.

1. Is this being caused by a conflict between the `center()` method and the `center` property of `UIView`?  If so, why isn't the type inferencing system figuring that out?
2. I've been burned by accidental variable shadowing too many times.  Is there a way to ask XCode to give me an error (or at least warn me) when I shadow a variable?